# yii\rest\UrlRule with "pluralize" rule is not working in Yii2 REST

Tags: php, api, yii2, advanced-rest-client

I am unable to access default endpoints with pluralize option, **view** action is also not working

**Case 1:**  Access without configure Module

```
'controllerNamespace' => 'api\controllers',

...

'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'country',   
        'tokens' => [
             '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
        ],
        /*'pluralize'=>false,*/
    ],
]
```

http://localhost/api/web/countries **Not working**

http://localhost/api/web/country is **working fine**

http://localhost/api/web/country/1 is **Not working**

**Case 2:**   Access via module **v1**

```
'modules' => [
     'v1' => [
          'basePath' => '@app/modules/v1',
          'class' => 'api\modules\v1\Module'
     ]
],

...

'rules' => [
     [
          'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 
          'controller' => ['country' => 'v1/country'],
          'tokens' => [
               '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
          ],
     ],
]
```

'pluralize' is not working completely and when access
**v1/country** & **v1/country/12** both giving same result as index action (country list)

Answer (score 1):

Your rule is incorrect you are missing the module name `v1` in your rules

```
[
     'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
     'controller' => 'v1/country',   
     'tokens' => [
          '{id}' => '<id:\\w+>'
     ],
     'extraPatterns' => [
          'GET index' => 'index',
     ],
],
```

Now you can access it with

```
http://localhost/api/web/v1/countries
```

Note : in order to enable the `POST` request along with `GET` add it to the extra patterns like  `'GET,POST index' => 'index',`

Comment: still getting same result 404

Comment: how are you accessing the url ? from the browser or sending a request via postman @RaveeSunshine see the answer i updated

Comment: using Advanced Rest Client (ARC) with GET request

Comment: ok and have you tried using the code after i updated, using `extraPatterns` ? i normally use postman to test the api @RaveeSunshine

Comment: Yes, but no change in result. 

v1/country & 
v1/country/12 

giving same result as index action (country list)