# Can I have both pluralized and not pluralized rules for Yii 2's yii\rest\UrlRule?

Tags: rest, yii2

I have disabled the default pluralization of my REST rules by setting [`yii\rest\UrlRule->pluralize = false`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-urlrule#$pluralize-detail) and now my *UserController* is accessible via:

- `GET user/<id>` -- returns the details of a user by its ID
- `GET user` - returns a list of all users
- `POST user` -- create a new user

I want to have second (and only this one) rule to be pluralized, so `GET users` returns a list of all users while `GET user/<id>` returns the details of a user. How can I achieve this?

I've tried [the following](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57572355/1469208):

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'pluralize' => false,
         'extraPatterns' => [
              'GET users' => 'user',
         ],
    ],
```

But this doesn't work. The `user/2` returns given user, the `user` return all users, but `users` ends up with 404.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to [use **two** rules](https://onezeronull.com/2021/06/03/pluralized-and-non-pluralized-rules-for-the-same-rest-controller/) to define such thing:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'user',
        'pluralize' => false,
         'except' => ['index'],
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller' => 'user',
         'patterns' => [
              'GET,HEAD' => 'index',
         ],
    ],
```

This will allow you to work on a single record using singular routes (i.e. `GET /user/7`, `DELETE /user/3`) and list all records using plural route (i.e. `GET users`). Details in the [source](https://onezeronull.com/2021/06/03/pluralized-and-non-pluralized-rules-for-the-same-rest-controller/).