# Standard RESTful controller or model ignores PUT verb in Yii 2

Tags: model-view-controller, model, controller, yii2

**tl;dr** *I have followed [the official guide](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start). Everything seems working except for `PUT`/`PATCH` verb. The `200 OK` code is returned, but the actual model isn't updated. What can be wrong?*

---

I have [created a blank Yii 2 project](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#installing-using-composer) that have [created a REST *UserController*](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#creating-controller) for already existing *User* model:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

I have modified the model to have all fields safe:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        [['username', 'email'], 'required'],
        [['username', 'email'], 'unique'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        [['password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'verification_token', 'auth_key', 'status,created_at', 'updated_at', 'password'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

I have [configured URL rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72491988/1469208) to have [both pluralized and non-pluralized paths](https://onezeronull.com/2021/06/03/pluralized-and-non-pluralized-rules-for-the-same-rest-controller/):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'user',
            'pluralize' => false,
            'except' => ['index'],
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'user',
            'patterns' => [
                'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS' => 'index',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I have [enabled JSON input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#enabling-json-input), if that matters:

```
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
]
```

[All the verbs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#trying-it-out) are processed correctly except for `PATCH /users/123` / `PUT /users/123`. When executed in Insomnia, I am getting `200 OK`, but the returned record shows no sign of modification:

[image]

What can be wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have maybe `updateScenario` in the controller set to something else than default?

Comment: The _full_ controller code is given in my question in the first block. As you can see, I have nothing there what isn't mentioned in the Yii 2 Guide.

Comment: This is really weird, since I'm using it all the time with PUT and it works...