# OPTION verb is not working for a list of all records in Yii 2 app

Tags: rest, yii2

I have [created a blank Yii 2 project](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation#installing-using-composer) that have [created a REST *UserController*](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#creating-controller) for already existing *User* model:

```
namespace app\controllers;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class UserController extends ActiveController
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';
}
```

I have modified the model to have all fields safe:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['status', 'default', 'value' => self::STATUS_INACTIVE],
        ['status', 'in', 'range' => [self::STATUS_ACTIVE, self::STATUS_INACTIVE, self::STATUS_DELETED]],
        [['username', 'email'], 'required'],
        [['username', 'email'], 'unique'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        [['password_hash', 'password_reset_token', 'verification_token', 'auth_key', 'status,created_at', 'updated_at', 'password'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

I have [configured URL rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72491988/1469208) to have [both pluralized and non-pluralized paths](https://onezeronull.com/2021/06/03/pluralized-and-non-pluralized-rules-for-the-same-rest-controller/):

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'user',
            'pluralize' => false,
            'except' => ['index'],
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller' => 'user',
            'patterns' => [
                'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS' => 'index',
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I have [enabled JSON input](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#enabling-json-input), if that matters:

```
'request' => [
    'parsers' => [
        'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    ]
]
```

[All the verbs](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#trying-it-out) are processed correctly except for `OPTIONS /users`:

When I execute `OPTIONS /user/20` then I am getting:

- 200 OK
- Empty content
- List of allowed methods

But, when I execute `OPTIONS users` then I am getting *405 Method not Allowed*.

[image]

What can be wrong or what am I missing?

Comment: Does it work when you change url rule from `'patterns' => ['GET,HEAD,OPTIONS' => 'index'],` to `'patterns' => ['GET,HEAD' => 'index', '' => 'options'],`?

Comment: @Bizley Yes, this is one of the solutions that worked. The other one is given below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `405 Method Not Allowed` not because of routing but because of [`yii\filters\VerbFilter`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-filters-verbfilter).

The `yii\rest\Controller` uses [`verbs()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/57ce3d3c94f918bf4bc9eac2bf7ef6112a3b9c9c/framework/rest/Controller.php#L60) method to set up `VerbFilter`.
The `yii\rest\ActiveController` [overrides](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/57ce3d3c94f918bf4bc9eac2bf7ef6112a3b9c9c/framework/rest/ActiveController.php#L111) `verbs()` method and sets `VerbFilter` to only allow `GET` and `HEAD` requests for `index` action.
It uses `options` action for `OPTIONS` method.

If you really want to use `index` action for `OPTIONS` method. You have to override `verbs()` method yourself and add `OPTIONS` as allowed method for that action. For example like this:

```php
protected function verbs()
{
    $verbs = parent::verbs();
    $verbs['index'][] = 'OPTIONS';
    return $verbs;
}
```

Or if you want to use `options` action you have to modify `patterns` settings  as suggested by **@Bizley** in comments.