# Why I don't have to specify verbs() for "GET" for my custom REST action?

Tags: rest, yii2, http-verbs

I have created a standard [`yii\rest\ActiveController`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller) and added my custom action to it:

```
public function actionTest($id)
{
    return ['test' => $id];
}
```

I have added a new entry to `extraPatterns` of `rules` of [`yii\web\UrlManager`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-urlmanager):

```
'extraPatterns' => [
    'GET test/{id}' => 'test',
],
```

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72573743/1469208), I have also added new verb definition in my REST controller:

```
public function verbs()
{
    $verbs = parent::verbs();
    $verbs['test'] = ['GET'];
    return $verbs;
}
```

But it turned out to be not needed. Meaning that I can comment out the above piece of code (the entire method in this case) and the whole new REST route is still working:

[image]

[image]

What am I missing? Why I don't need to specify this new action / router in [`verbs()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-rest-activecontroller#verbs()-detail) for `GET` (I figured out that I must do this for other verbs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the referenced question/answer you were working with existing action `index` that already had rule for `yii\filters\VerbFilter` to only allow `GET` or `HEAD` verbs for that action.

But in case of completely new action `test` there is no existing rule for `VerbFilter`. If there is no rule for action the `VerbFilter` will allow any request. That's why if you don't specify rule for `test` action any verb set up in router will work. Once you specify the rule for `test` in `verbs()` method, only allowed verbs will make it through `VerbFilter`.